# How to add method called after another method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns

There is a class that has many methods, all returning string(url). I want to add new method called after any of the previous ones, which adds extra parameter to url. Example would be :
 `Class.method.my_method` 
returning 
`www.domain.com/xxx/xxx?my_method_return`
    What would be the best way of doing this? 

Also is there any source where i could find solutions for similar problems? I posted it here as I'm not sure where else I could look for answer.

Comment: Can you not use `String#concat` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation `Class.method` indicates a class method.  But your description sounds like a standard method `Class#method`.  To clarify, the latter is equivalent to `Class.new.method`.  I here assume your question is related to the latter.

I think a standard strategy is to use an instance variable which holds the information of the url processed so far.
Here is an example.

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :url  # defines the reading method "url"
  def initialize(baseurl)
    @url = baseurl
  end

  def my_method1
    @url << "?" + "my_method1_return"
  end

  def my_method2
    @url << "?" + "my_method2_return"
  end
end

my_url   = MyClass.new('www.domain.com/xxx/xxx')
string_url0 = my_url.url         # => 'www.domain.com/xxx/xxx'
string_url1 = my_url.my_method1  # => 'www.domain.com/xxx/xxx?my_method1_return'
string_url2 = my_url.my_method2  # => 'www.domain.com/xxx/xxx?my_method1_return?my_method2_return'
my_url.url        # == string_url2 == 'www.domain.com/xxx/xxx?my_method1_return?my_method2_return'
```

As for the general source of information, I think the issue is related to a fundamental design-pattern of OOP, as tagged rightly.
So, I can't think of any shortcut, but a programmer learns over the years by studying it with textbooks, actual programming, etc...

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions would be to dynamically create a module and [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-prepend) it to the original class. Let’s say we have this class:

```
class Origin
  def m1; "foo"; end
  def m2; "bar"; end  
end 

Origin.instance_methods(false)
#=> [
#  [0] m1() Origin (unbound)
#  [1] m2() Origin (unbound)
# ]
```

Let’s define our module, going through the methods of the original class (or we might alternatively pass a list of methods we want to overwrite):

```
Appender = Module.new do
  # might be just %i[m1 m2].each do |m|  
  Origin.instance_methods(false).each do |m|  
    define_method m do |*args|    
      super(*args) + "?answer=42"      
    end  
  end  
end
```

Now let’s prepend it to the original class:

```
Origin.prepend Appender
```

And voilà:

```
Origin.new.m1
#⇒ "foo?answer=42"
Origin.new.m2
#⇒ "bar?answer=42"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `yield` statement to the end of your method, then pass a block to  adds extra parameter to url.

For example

```
class MyClass
  def my_method url
    # do some operation on url
    yield url
  end
end
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
m = MyClass.new
m.my_method("url") do |url|
  # do some operation on url
end
```